# How to get amount of pixels from top to div block in Android WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I want to receive position of div block at `WebView` and show my view over `WebView` by using height from top to div as a padding for my view.

I write some code:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:{" +
        " var ad = document.getElementById('iAD1');" +
        " Advertisement.showAdvertising(ad.offsetTop, ad.offsetBottom);" +
        " }"
    );
```

But the size is smaller that this block shows at the `WebView`. I'm not good in javascript so I think that I missed something meaningful or just use wrong parameter.

Could you tell me how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

try this one :) it works for me..

```
function detectmob() { 
 if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
 ){
    return true;
  }
 else {
    return false;
  }
}
```